# How to i make dynamic pdf using php?

Tags: php, pdf

I want to create a dynamic pdf using php. I wrote a simple php code.
Downloaded the fpdf library and used it. But there's no output when I run it on xamp.
I have taken input from a registration form and want to print it on to the pdf.
The pdf appears to be blank.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
{
$f_name=$_POST['name1'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['psw'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$phoneno=$_POST['phoneno'];

require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->cell(0,10,'welcome{f_name}',1,0,'C');   
$pdf->output();
}
?>
```

Comment: Turn on all error reporting so you will see any errors that might be happening. `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: It would probably be easier to create a pdf by using html2pdf.
https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/doc/README.md